# MySQL query with DATE_FORMAT() to Laravel Querybuilder (or Eloquent)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get records from a table on a specific day.
Dates's format: datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS)

I'm trying to translate a MySQL query to Laravel query builder. But I don't know how to deal with the DATE_FORMAT().

Here is MySQL query

```sql
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN customers ON events.id_customer = customers.id
WHERE start_date > DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
AND end_date < DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-16", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
;
```

In my controller I get a date (string) that I put into a DateTime

```php
$date_datetime = new \DateTime(Input::get('date_string'));
```

And then change its format

```php
$query_date = date_format($date_datetime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I've tried the following code, but it is obviously not working

```php
$pdf_events = DB::table('events')
->join('customers', 'events.id_customer', '=', 'customers.id')
->select(...)
->whereRaw("start_date > DATE_FORMAT($query_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')")
->whereRaw("end_date < DATE_FORMAT($query_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')+1")
->get();
```

Comment: I think you don't need `DATE_FORMAT` here, just use `start_date > $query_date`.

Comment: You *do* need `start_date >=  $query_date` in place of `start_date >  $query_date` -- notice the `>=` -- unless you want to filter out the rows with `start_date` at precisely midnight on `$query_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for handling DateTime in Laravel since it has support out of the box.

Now, how to use it to resolve your problem?

First, you need to convert your input into `Carbon` object.

```php
$start_date = Carbon::parse(Input::get('date_string'));

// Assuming you want the end date 1 day later at same time
$end_date = $start_date->addDay();


// You could change the format with format() but in this case we don't need to
```

Then in your Eloquent, you can use the `Carbon` Datetime object to query using `where()`

```php
$pdf_events = DB::table('events')
->join('customers', 'events.id_customer', '=', 'customers.id')
->select(...)
->where("start_date", ">", $start_date)
->where("end_date", "<", $end_date)
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Carbon ([doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)) objects to compare dates. For example:

```
->where('start_date', '=', Carbon::now())
```

You can build a custom Carbon object for a custom date-time to pass into the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `DATE_FORMAT`, Try this:

```php
$query_start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", request()->date_string);

// Add 1 day to the date
$query_end_date = $query_start_date->addDay();



$pdf_events = DB::table('events')
    ->join('customers', 'events.id_customer', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->where(
        [
            ["start_date", ">", $query_start_date],
            ["end_date", "<", $query_end_date]
        ]
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Datetime;

$end_date1 = $request->input('end_date');
$EndDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $end_date1);
$end_date = $EndDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

try like this its work for me